# Use of "being" without "to" in passive construction

Tags: passive-voice

> I look forward to being interviewed on the current affairs programme.

It is in passive construction, hence ***to*** has been placed before ***being***. Am I right?

> How could she think of the baby being born in the house?-AY Byatt, 1985.

Does this sentence contain passive construction? I think it does. If it contains a passive construction, why ***to*** preposition has not been placed before ***being***? It would be better if I got some sentences similar to this sentence, containing **being+past participle** without the preposition ***to***.

Answer (score 1):

The "to" belongs to the verb to look forward to sth as in Children look forward to Christmas. The "to" has nothing to do with passive.

The passive is the conjugation of to be + past participle:
is written, was written, will be written etc.

"being" is placed before the past participle to form passive continuous:
is being built, was being built etc.

There is nowhere the word to.

Here's a website showing active and passive verb forms:

http://english-zone.com/verbs/pssvchrt.html